# (In)formal languages and meaning of words

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein

I vaguely remember having heard that one can formally prove that no amount of (successful) communication between two people ensures that the assigned meaning of their words converges. I think it had something to do with Wittgenstein's thoughts on colors.

It would be great to get a reference and/or name for that statement.

Thanks in advance for any help on the matter. Cheers,
Lukas

Comment: Maybe the ref is to [*Remarks on Colour* (German: *Bemerkungen über die Farben*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remarks_on_Colour): was one of Ludwig Wittgenstein's last works, written in Oxford in 1950, the year before he died.

Comment: See also [Indeterminacy of translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminacy_of_translation): a thesis propounded by 20th-century American analytic philosopher W. V. Quine.

Answer (score 1):

On the formal side of things, [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) makes similar arguments.

> The theorem applies more generally to any sufficiently strong formal system, showing that truth in the standard model of the system cannot be defined within the system.

Of course, Tarski's actual proof is in a far more exacting mathematical form regarding the truth value of statements.  Amusingly it is still subject to itself!

We also have a computational equivalent, if that is preferred. [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) states that all non-trivial semantic properties of programs in a Turing Complete language are undecidable.

Comment: And I am morally obliged to link Guy Steele's [Growing a Language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ahvzDzKdB0) speech (and its [transcript](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/steele.pdf)) when people ask about communicating the meaning of words.  While he clearly sidesteps the particular requirement you seek (converged meaning without a common language to build from), his particular sidestep is still fascinating to me.